# IplImage to vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, opencv

How can I convert `IplImage` to `vector<uint8_t>` . I can convert it if I send image path to function like :

```
bool faceImg::load_file (const string &path, vector<uint8_t> &data)
{
    data.clear();

    std::ifstream is(path.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!is.is_open())
        return false;

    is.seekg(0, is.end);
    size_t len = (size_t)is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0, is.beg);
    data.resize(len);
    is.read((char*)data.data(), len);

    return true;
}
```

However I want to rewrite function with IplImage from camera capture :

```
bool faceImg::load_image(IplImage *image, vector<uint8_t> &data)
{

}
```

Comment: `IplImage` has `char* imageData` member which points to image raw data - the same data as you read from file. Assuming that image has 8 bpp format, you can copy the whole `imageData` memory to the vector. Use alo the following IplImage members: `imageSize, width, height`

Comment: So I do not need any convertion ?

Comment: No, if IplImage has required format IPL_DEPTH_8U, see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#IplImage `int depth` member.

Comment: 1. do not use IplImages, but cv::Mat.  2. do not try to read anything manually, but use cv::imread() / cv::imdecode()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the function you want to have. You can probably optimize it similar to the version that maxint provides (but reshaping might alter the input IplImage?!?).

The function should work with any number of channels but it assumes 8 bit types (e.g. 8 bit grayscale image or 24 bit BGR images).

here's my function:

```
// you dont need this typedef!
typedef unsigned char uint8_t ;

// probably not the fastest way ;)
// returns a vector with this ordering:
// x=0; y=0; Blue Channel value
// x=0; y=0; Green Channel value
// x=0; y=0; Red Channel value
// x=1; y=0; Blue Channel value
// ...
bool load_image(IplImage *image, std::vector<uint8_t> &data)
{
    if(image->depth != 8) return false;

    // only allocate the memory once
    data.reserve(image->width*image->height* image->nChannels);

    unsigned char * imgPtr = (unsigned char*) image->imageData;

    for(unsigned int y=0; y<image->height; ++y)
        for(unsigned int x=0; x<image->width; ++x)
            for(unsigned int c=0; c<image->nChannels; ++c)
            {
                unsigned char * valuePtr = imgPtr + y*image->widthStep + x*image->nChannels + c;
                data.push_back(*valuePtr);
            }

    return true;
}
```

I used this function to test:

```
int main()
{
    //cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("../inputData/Lenna.png");

    // your IplImage, this one is 24 bit BGR format
    IplImage * yourImage = &(IplImage)input;

    // your vector
    std::vector<uint8_t> data;

    // your function call to load that image to a vector
    load_image(yourImage, data);

    // unit test: check whether pixel in cv::Mat are the same as the ones in the vector
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<input.rows; ++j)
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<input.cols; ++i)
        {
            if(input.channels() == 3)
            {
                cv::Vec3b pixel = input.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
                for(unsigned int c=0; c<input.channels(); ++c)
                {
                    if(pixel[c] != data[input.channels()*j*input.rows + input.channels()*i +c])
                        std::cout << "different values at: (" << i << "," << j << "): " << (int)pixel[c] << " vs " << (int)data[input.channels()*j*input.rows + input.channels()*i +c] << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else if(input.channels() == 1)
            {
                unsigned char pixel = input.at<unsigned char>(j,i);
                for(unsigned int c=0; c<input.channels(); ++c)
                {
                    if(pixel != data[input.channels()*j*input.rows + input.channels()*i +c])
                        std::cout << "different values at: (" << i << "," << j << "): " << (int)pixel << " vs " << (int)data[input.channels()*j*input.rows + input.channels()*i +c] << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }


    cvNamedWindow("IplImage");
    cvShowImage("IplImage", yourImage);


    cv::imshow("input", input);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
image.reshape(1, 1).copyTo(v);
```

`cv::Mat` (C++ API) is preferred than `IplImage` (C API) from OpenCV 2.0. `reshape()` is needed as the video frame may be have multiple channels or multiple rows. It does not modify the original `image` structure (@Micka), instead, return a header structure with new channels and new rows. It works **ONLY** when image data is continuous where `image.step == image.width * image.elemSize()`. Otherwise, use the following code:

```
vector<uint8_t> v(image.total());
image.copyTo(Mat(image.size(), TYPE_8U, &v[0]));
```

**Reference**

- [Mat::reshape()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=reshape#Mat%20Mat::reshape%28int%20cn,%20int%20rows%29%20const)
- [Mat::copyTo()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=reshape#void%20Mat::copyTo%28OutputArray%20m%29%20const)

Answer (score 2):

assuming, you use cv::Mat(and you *must*), and also assuming, that your Mat is continuous, it's quite easy, to make a `vector<uchar>` from the data pointer:

```
Mat ocv = ...

vector<uchar> vec( ocv.data, (ocv.data + ocv.total()*ocv.elemSize()) );
```

if again you want a *complete* image, like on disk, use [imencode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode)

```
Mat ocv = ...
vector<uchar> vec;
imencode("png",ocv,vec);
```